# Phabricator GUI is not showning... facing some script and/or server issue

Tags: phabricator

I am trying to do some hands on with phabricator. Few days before I tried to set it up using the official setup link:
[Official installation link](https://secure.phabricator.com/book/phabricator/article/installation_guide/) 
But following this link I was getting '**path**' not set problem and even following solutions available online, I couldn't resolve that issue.
So tried [another link](https://github.com/arrivu/beacon/wiki/Phabricator-Installation-Guide-(Project-Management-For-PHP)).
A day before yesterday I was able to use every available feature in from phabricator's UI but after a restart I am stuck with its UI and getting below given text while trying to access the server:

```
setException($ex);PhabricatorStartup::endOutputCapture();$sink->writeResponse($response); } catch (Exception $response_exception) { // If we hit a rendering exception, ignore it and throw the original // exception. It is generally more interesting and more likely to be // the root cause. throw $ex; } } } catch (Exception $ex) { PhabricatorStartup::didEncounterFatalException('Core Exception', $ex, false); } function phabricator_startup() { // Load the PhabricatorStartup class itself. $t_startup = microtime(true); $root = dirname(dirname(__FILE__)); require_once $root.'/support/PhabricatorStartup.php'; // If the preamble script exists, load it. $t_preamble = microtime(true); $preamble_path = $root.'/support/preamble.php'; if (file_exists($preamble_path)) { require_once $preamble_path; } $t_hook = microtime(true); PhabricatorStartup::didStartup($t_startup); PhabricatorStartup::recordStartupPhase('startup.init', $t_startup); PhabricatorStartup::recordStartupPhase('preamble', $t_preamble); PhabricatorStartup::recordStartupPhase('hook', $t_hook); }
```

This is the content of file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
    # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
    # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
    # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
    # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
    # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
    # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
    #ServerName www.example.com

    ServerAdmin myhost.co.in 
    DocumentRoot /var/www/phabricator/webroot

    # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
    # error, crit, alert, emerg.
    # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
    # modules, e.g.
    #LogLevel info ssl:warn

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
    # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
    # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
    # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
    # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
    #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule ^/rsrc/(.*)     -                       [L,QSA]
    RewriteRule ^/favicon.ico   -                       [L,QSA]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$          /index.php?__path__=$1 [B,L,QSA]
    <Directory "/var/www/phabricator/webroot">
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: The guide you used is incorrect and not supported.

Comment: have you solved this? I am also getting same error. Please provide the solution.

Comment: Hi @AniketKulkarni I was doing that as part of my R&D work... I was able to do after a setting up from scratch... but regarding this issue I was not able to verify if the solutions suggested can fix it. If you are able to have fix it or below suggested solutions fixes the issue please update the same here as well so other users might be benefited.

Answer (score 0):

Install PHP. This is required.

Comment: I have checked the env the php libraries are installed. Still getting the same error

Comment: Something in your environment is not correctly configured. Are you using a shared host, by chance?  To be clear, this is not a problem with Phabricator, but in how your server is configured to execute PHP.